# Number of spatial lines

Tags: r, spatial, convex-hull, r-sp, concave-hull

Is there a way to find out the number of continuous spatial lines in a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` ?

EG this would be `2` (the outer one and the inner one) :

[image: small alpha]

And this would be `1` :

[image: big alpha]

(Also, is there a way to get the total length of each of them ?)

Comment: What's the code + data to reproduce both figures?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `length(sln)` (where 'sln' is your `SpatialLinesDataFrame`) to get the number of features (e.g., lines) and 
 `gLength(sln, byid = TRUE)` from **rgeos** to get the single line lengths.

```
## sample data
library(trajectories)
data(storms)

sln <- as(storms, "SpatialLinesDataFrame")

## number of features
length(sln)
# [1] 4

## length of each feature (throws warning since 'sln' is not projected)
rgeos::gLength(sln, byid = TRUE)
# 2012_TONY-ALBERTO  2011_SEAN-ARLENE   2010_TOMAS-ALEX      2009_IDA-ONE 
#      831.0649          705.1888          804.7706          355.7562
```

But be aware that `length` does not automatically return the number of lines when dealing with multi-line features. If you do the following, for instance,

```
plot(sln[1, ])
```

[image: plot]

you see that the first feature of our 4-line `SpatialLinesDataFrame` is a non-continuous spatial line consisting of several sub-lines. To get the number of sub-lines from a discontinuous line feature, you are required to do something like the following.

```
length(sln[1, ]@lines[[1]]@Lines)
# [1] 19
```